# OpenCV, Android: Draw Line on bitmap

Tags: java, android, opencv, bitmap

I currently have an application that `onClick` will draw a green bounding rectangle around the battery and the blue strip of paper. I would also like to have the button `onClick` draw a line from the battery to the strip of paper(as shown in second picture below). Currently I am able to get the all the x and y values of the rectangles, thus knowing that I need to draw a line from `534,1261` to `788,1261` and have the line labeled with the x difference as shown in picture.

[image: Current Image]

[image: ![Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For drawing lines and text You can use code like that:

```
Point firstPoint = new Point(100, 200);
Point secondPoint = new Point(100, 400);
Point middlePoint = new Point(firstPoint.x,
        firstPoint.y + 0.5 * (secondPoint.y -  firstPoint.y));

Scalar lineColor = new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255);
int lineWidth = 3;

Scalar textColor = new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255);

Imgproc.line(sourceMat, firstPoint, secondPoint, lineColor, lineWidth);
Imgproc.putText(sourceMat, " Text" , middlePoint,
        Core.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.5 , textColor);
```

Where `sourceMat` - `Mat` with image.

And for determining of line "height" in cm (approximately) You should use "height" of battery rectangle :

```
lineHeightCm = 4.46 / heightOfBatteryRectangleInPixels * lineHeightInPixels;
```

where 4.46 - "height" of AAA battery in cm.